# Is there geometry on algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, metric-spaces

Term algebra is the set of words that can be generated by some grammar. Such algebra can be grounded (e.g. concept grounding research in philosophy), can have semantics and this semantics can determine the distance between words. E.g. in neural network applications each word has assigned vector and the semantic distance between those words can be expressed as the distance between vectors.

My question is - is there some general theory how to define distances between words (semantic or syntactic) and how to research the geometry/topology/metric space that is built upon algebra?

I am just interested in building semantic models with some help and suggestions of mathematics and that is why I am asking if the mathematics have some general tools already?

Comment: See for example [geometric group theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_group_theory).

Comment: The hamming metric is one such means by which to calculate the distance between words. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance